# Customer Added by IPP Api are not listed on quckbook online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have created custom app on quickbook
i am trying to add the customer from my localhost
but not succeed, i am using Keith SDK
Out put are

An error occurred -1092: XML parser said: 6: No XML content to parse.

However i got successful outh token,key from quickbook.
Is realmID is different for FLAVOR_ONLINE,FLAVOR_DESKTOP?
when i used flavor desktop 
data seems to added.
but failed with flavor online 
please help

Answer (score 1):

This:

> An error occurred -1092: XML parser said: 6: No XML content to parse.

Usually indicates that you did something wrong. But no one will be able to tell you exactly what went wrong because you didn't really provide enough detail.

Post your code.

Post your XML request (e.g. print($Service->lastRequest()));

Post your XML response (e.g. print($Service->lastResponse()));

> Is realmID is different for FLAVOR_ONLINE,FLAVOR_DESKTOP?

Each QuickBooks company file (regardless of whether it's a QuickBooks for Windows realm or a QuickBooks Online realm) will have a unique realm ID. The realm ID is the unique identifier for a QuickBooks company.

If you're using a single realm ID for both a QuickBooks Online company and a QuickBooks desktop company, then that's certainly a problem.